# How to apply masking to numeric field with a trailing character

Tags: javascript, jquery, numeric, masking

I have a `numeric(15,2)` field. I want to apply masking to it with a trailing character.

Let's say

```
var x = 789.98;
```

output :

```
789.98x
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you really mean to just add a character?

```js
var x = number + 'x';
```

If you meant to mask the last one you can do

```js
var x = number.substring(0, number.length - 1) + 'x';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to add a character to the end of the input value? If so, here is an example you can work from. I put a little validation in this example so you can ignore it. Here's a pen with the example in which I think you're asking for - https://codepen.io/CodeHero1/pen/MWyBZJq

```
 $(function () {
   
   $('[name="myinput"]').on('keyup',function(){
     
         if($(this).val().length === 5){
           
           var $this = $(this);
           var inputvalue = $this.val();
           var specialcharacter = 'X';
           $(this).val(inputvalue + specialcharacter);
           
         }
     
      });
    });
```